# Manga/Manhwa about a girl who is a poison master and is transported to another world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, cultivation

She is transported to another world, because Yama can't decide what to do with her, because she released her research, and it cured cancer or all kinds of diseases, but she poisoned a lot of people in her original world. Been looking, but can't seem to find it. She also knows how to create poison food and finds a black snake king. I'm pretty sure there was a cultivation angle too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this manga mostly in black & white or in full colour?

Comment: _"She is transported to another world because yama can't decide what to do,"_ Also, what the does the word 'yama' refer to? Is that a character's name? A typo?

Comment: @LogicDictates - Yama is a death god in Hindu mythology

Comment: @Valorum - It's far from clear that that's what the OP was referring to though. If they'd typed the word with a capital 'y', I'd assume it was a name, but they didn't.

Comment: @LogicDictates - See below

Comment: @Valorum - Looks like a good fit, but without that story having been found, guessing that it was a reference to a Hindu god was a stab in the dark without confirmation from the OP.

Comment: @LogicDictates - Hardly a stab. Yama is a pretty common deity in manga, especially Isekai and Reincarnation.

Comment: @Valorum - Gods of some sort are common in such manga, but they're fictional gods more often than not. I don't believe I've ever seen a manga featuring the Hindu god Yama as a character, until the example you just posted. Also, I just did a search for "[manga] yama" on this site, and this thread was the sole result.

Comment: @LogicDictates - I've read dozens of Manhwa with Lord Yama or Yama the Death God, etc.

Comment: @Valorum - Fine, but I haven't, so I was looking for confirmation directly from the OP, not a guess from you.

Comment: @LogicDictates - My guesses are better than confirmation from a hundred OPs

Comment: @Valorum - In that case, why don't post your guesses as answers more often, rather than relying so much on evidence?

Answer (score 5):

This is *Bad Girl's Punishment Games* (AKA *Villain Girl's Punishment Game*).

> An evil woman is born again! She has to brush up on achievements and virtue and fighting villains.
> Starting from now, I, Xiao Yi Xin, want to dominate the different world!
> lol….. Wait! The Fire Immortal Lord ….. I just helped you to dissolve your fire poison in order to brush up on achievements and virtue. I’m not really going to be your real wife.
> Let me go!

[image]

Comment: thanks been working for awhile what it was!